# How to check if an objects attribute is given?

Tags: html, django, database

I am trying to make a little website with django when I ran into a problem:

I have a site where I want to look at a post in detail, but not every post has an image attribute - so I am getting an error when I try to display images, since some arent existent.

So the solution would be to check if an image is given, but... How do I do that?
I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
</div>
    <p>{{ object.content }}</p>

    {% if object.image.url == True %} <!-- In no case an image is displayed -->
        <p>
            <img src="{{ object.image.url }}">
        </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the *truthiness* `object.image` attribute, not its URL, so:

```
{% if object.image %}
    <p><img src="{{ object.image.url }}"></p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @Tknoobs: because if there is no image, then `object.image` is `None`, and thus has no `.url` attribute, and is also not equal to `True`.